# Set difference of real numbers and rational numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $\mathbb{R}$ is the set of real numbers and $\mathbb{Q}$ is the set of rational numbers,then what is $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$?
The answer is irrational numbers.

My question is the reason behind this fact.

Comment: The irrational numbers are defined as belonging to the real numbers but not the rational numbers, i.e. the definition is $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Thank you.But its not my answer.Can you show me the procedure of solving this problem,in steps?

Comment: There is no problem here. It's a definition.

Comment: I mean that the answer should have been the set of all natural,whole numbers,integers and irrational numbers.but here only the irrational nos. are mentioned.Anyways,thanks.

Comment: Natural numbers, integers *are included in the set of rational numbers. The set of irrational numbers includes all real numbers that are not rational.

Answer (score 2):

The set of irrational numbers is defined as the set of all real numbers
that are not rationals.

This is presicly $\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}$ which denotes 
$$
\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid x\not\in\mathbb{Q}\}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Well, the real numbers are formed by the union of the rational numbers and the irrational numbers.

That is,

$\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{Q}\cup (\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q})$, so if you took away all the rational numbers, you would only be left with the irrationals.

---

If you are wondering why $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ isn't $\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$, or something like that, it is because both $\mathbb{N},\mathbb{Z}\subset\mathbb{Q}.$ That is, the natural numbers and integers are rational numbers, so when you take $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$, you are removing all rational numbers from $\mathbb{R}$. This includes removing $\mathbb{N},\mathbb{Z}$ as well.