# proof that $\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{Q}\cup\mathbb{Q}^{'}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, real-numbers, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

I'm not sure if this is correct or not, I'm trying to find a proof or disproof that $\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{Q}\cup\mathbb{Q}^{'}$, that means, the set of the real numbers is the union of the rational and irrational numbers, if possible I'd like a more explicative answer since I'm not that good in math, thanks in advance!

Comment: As I know, irrational numbers are simply defined as "real numbers which are not rational". So just by the definition $\mathbb{Q'}=\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/760430/set-difference-of-real-numbers-and-rational-numbers

Comment: What is the definition of irrational numbers that you use in that context?

Comment: Perhaps $\mathbb{Q'}$ is the set of limit points of the rational sequences. Then the claim is that  $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in  $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I didn't know that irrational numbers were "real numbers which are not rational", I was taught that irrational numbers are simply numbers that can't be described as a fraction, that's why the name irrational, they can't be described as a ratio. Thanks for the information though

Comment: Well yes, real numbers which can't be described as a fraction, this is the same thing as real numbers which are not rational. Still, they are by definition real numbers.

Comment: @TheWonkaBro in that sentence when you say "simply numbers", you're likely thinking about real numbers, which is what the other commenters are getting at. This is also how everyone else defines them. Otherwise, what do you mean by a "number"? Certainly you're describing some class of numbers, as you seem to understand that $\pi \cdot i$ doesn't belong to your set of irrationals.

Comment: " I was taught that irrational numbers are simply numbers that can't be described as a fraction" Then what's the definition of *rational* numbers?  They are the numbers that *CAN* be described as a fraction.  That's why they are called rational, the *can* be described as a ration....  So the The rationals UNION the irrationals = the numbers that CAN do something UNION the numbers that CAN"T do something = All numbers.  That's all there is to it.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now, thanks everyone

Comment: Another way of looking at it is how do you partition real numbers up.  Well, you have real numbers that are rationall... and you have real numbers that are *not*.  And that's .... really all there is to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb Q =\{x\in \mathbb R|$ there are integers $n,m$ so that $x = \frac mn\}$.

$\mathbb Q' = \{x\in \mathbb R|$ there are *not* any integers $n,m$ so that $=\frac mn\}$

So $\mathbb Q\cup \mathbb Q' = \{x\in \mathbb R|$ there are integers $n,m$ so that $x = \frac mn\}\cup \{x\in \mathbb R|$ there are not any integers $n,m$ so that $=\frac mn\}=$

$\{x\in \mathbb R|$ there are integers $n,m$ so that $x=\frac mn$ or there are not any integers $n,m$ sothat $x=\frac mn\}=$.

$\{x\in \mathbb R|$ there are or are not integers $n,m$ where $x=\frac mn\}=$

$\{x\in \mathbb R| x$ can be any real number whather it can be written as $x=\frac mn$ for some integers $m,n$ or not$\}=$

$\{x\in \mathbb R|x$ is a real number$\}=$

$\{x\in \mathbb R\}=$

$\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing to prove: an irrational number is **by definition** a real number that is not a rational number, so by definition every real number is either rational or irrational (and not both).